# Webpack-dev-server

Tags: javascript, webpack

Никак не могу разобраться как настроить webpack-dev-server на автообновление страницы в хроме при изменении html документа.
При изменении sass/js файлов всё работает
SOS

Answer (score 1):

Для поддержки автообновления HTML нужно добавить в `webpack.config.js` плагин `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.
Пример настройки:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html', // Имя файла на выходе
    template: './public/index.html', // Путь к шаблону
    inject: 'body', // Куда инъецировать bundle.js (head/body/необязательно)
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: '404.html',
    template: './public/404.html',
    inject: 'body',
  }),
]
```

Comment: HtmlWebpackPlugin is not defined, хотя я установил его в devDependencies

Comment: @sergey А про `var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('HtmlWebpackPlugin')` не забыли?